# Examples of applications of graph genus?

Tags: graph-theory

So I'm reading for the first time about genus of graphs and I'm confused about, what's the reason for this concept?

What are genus used for?

Why does one want to embed a graph on some topological shape and why is one interested about the number of holes in it?

Comment: What's the maximal chromatic number of a genus zero graph?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown How's that related to the genus?